# Monotonicity of the sequence $ ( F_n^{\frac{1}{n}} ) $, where $ ( F_n ) $ is the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Let $ F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} $ with $ F_0 = 1 $, $ F_1 = 1 $ (the Fibonacci sequence). I would like to know whether $ F_n^{\frac{1}{n}} $ is monotonically increasing in $ n $. It is not difficult to show (by induction) that this sequence is bounded from above by, and converges to $ \phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $. By direct inspection of the first few terms, it seems to be monotonic, and I suppose that some simple induction argument can prove this, but somehow I can't make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: It should follow directly from the [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Answer (score 1):

From Binet's formula

$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi - \psi}; \qquad \varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \psi = 1 - \varphi = -\frac{1}{\varphi},$$

we obtain

$$\log F_n = \log \frac{\varphi^n(1 - (\psi/\varphi)^n)}{\sqrt{5}} = n\log \varphi - \frac12\log 5 + \log (1 - (-\psi^2)^n),$$

and hence

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\log F_{n+1}- \frac1n\log F_n = \frac{\log 5}{2n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n+1}\log(1-(-\psi^2)^{n+1}) - \frac{1}{n}\log(1-(-\psi^2)^n).$$

Since $\lvert\psi\rvert < 1$, the $\frac{\log 5}{2n(n+1)}$ term dominates, and the sequence is certainly monotonically increasing for large enough $n$.

We can estimate

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\log F_{n+1} - \frac1n\log F_n \geqslant \frac{\log 5}{2n(n+1)} - \frac{4}{n} \lvert\psi\rvert^{2n}$$

and see that that is positive for all $n > 3$. The remaining cases can easily be verified by hand.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot!